# How to push datas to backend only if the status was closed in all rows

Tags: php, mysql

student table :

```
ID      Stud_Id    subject      option    status
1       01          A              y      closed
2       01          B              Y      closed
3       01          C              n      pending
4       02          A              y      closed
5       02          B              y      closed
6       02          C              y      closed
```

Result Table:

```
ID      Stud_Id    subject      option    status   Result
1       02          A              y      closed   Pass
2       02          B              y      closed   Pass
3       02          C              y      closed   Pass
```

I am trying to select data from student table , I need to select data only if the status is closed for particular student id and push the values to result table by setting status as PASS/FAIL based option Yes/No .

Can anyone help me with this using MYSQL

Comment: What is "id"????

Comment: its just a row id of table .

Comment: So what's it doing in the result?

Comment: I have row ids for updating option and row values since that is the only unique value i have in the table . suggest me if there is a best way

Comment: ID has no meaning in the result. Get rid of it.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this Query:

```
INSERT INTO result_table(Stud_Id,subject,option,status) 
VALUES
(SELECT Stud_Id,subject,option,status FROM student_table where 
id='student_id' and status='closed');
```